# Tmux bind alt+arrowkey to resize pane

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I can't seem to get <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>arrow key</kbd> to bind to resize my panes on tmux.

My `.tmux.conf`

```
# Set window titles
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g set-titles on

# Start windows number @1 Instead of @0
set -g base-index 1
set-window-option -g pane-base-index 1

# Renumber windows when closing
set -g renumber-windows on

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g status-keys vi
set -g history-limit 20000

setw -g mode-keys vi
setw -g monitor-activity on

set-option -g default-shell $SHELL

bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"

set -g mouse on

bind -n M-Left resize-pane -L 10
bind -n M-Right resize-pane -R 10
bind -n M-Up resize-pane -U 10
bind -n M-Down resize-pane -D 10

# Use Alt-vim keys without prefix to switch panes
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
bind -n M-j select-pane -D 
bind -n M-k select-pane -U
bind -n M-l select-pane -R

# Shift arrow to switch windows
bind -n S-Left  previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window

# Remove escape key press delay
set -g escape-time 0

# Reload tmux config
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

When I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> nothing happens.

Can someone tell me where to find logs or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can run tmux with -vv to generate log files but there will be a lot of information in them so it may be tricky to pinpoint what is wrong.

Are you sure TERM outside tmux is correct for your terminal? If it is not then tmux may not recognise the arrow keys, or may expect something different than the terminal is sending.

Comment: I tried running with `-vv` couldn't find and log files. Not sure what you mean "`TERM` outside tmux is correct for terminal", could you elaborate? What's confusing to me here is that `Alt + hjkl` works, it moves me between panes and `Shift + arrow keys` also work, it moves me between windows.

Comment: You need to kill tmux entirely (`tmux kill-server`) and then start with `-vv`. The log files will be in the directory where you started tmux. M-hjkl do not depend on TERM so they are not a good test. Are you sure your terminal or WM doesn't steal the meta arrow keys so tmux doesn't get them? If shift works that seems more likely than a TERM problem. If you run `cat` *outside* tmux and press M-Left, what do you see?